# Problem connecting 3G Dongle that works without dialer

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to connect internet on my Raspberry PI using a 3G Dongle. I am not a network guy and don't understand the difference between different types of dongle available. All the example and help I have found online is related to USB Dongle which basically requires dialing. I have also thoroughly studied the usb_modeswitch. In my case I am using a Dongle which is sim free and does not requires dialing. When I connect the Dongle with my Laptop it connects automatically and I have to then connect to the Wifi connection that it creates automatically. Now for so many hour I struggled with usb_switchmode to get my Dongle recognized as Modem and it fails to switch. Now I am thinking that maybe it is not a Modem at all because it does not requires dialing. It just need to be plugged in and it connects automatically. Am I right with this? So If I connect the Dongle with Raspberry PI, I will just have to connect with the Wifi connection that it creates?

Comment: what make and model dongle?

Comment: Model is Huawei E315-5

Comment: What did you try?